Results from Strahler order/Stream rank (order) "cut" into squares - why?
I have DEM (30m/px) from SRTM, but when I run the SAGA Strahler order in QGIS 3.30 I get strange results - see below.
Why is the image is "cut" into squares of 1km?


These SRTM data use a geographic projection. Data with geographic projections result in these strange artifacts as described at Removing strange gdaldem hillshade artifacts. Reproject your surface model into UTM and try again.
